# Can not send email from host account to user email while resetting password

Tags: django

I have made a smtp configuration in my django app settings, which will sent a email in users account to reset password.but whenever i enter the form it causes an error like `TimeoutError at /password_reset/  [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Comment: Can you share your email configuration from your Django settings.py file? Be sure to redact any usernames / passwords.

Comment: #smtp confuguration

EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=578
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST_USER='my mail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'

Comment: Did you enable "less secure" in your Gmail settings? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en  Otherwise you won't be able to connect. Also, you cannot enable "less secure" if you use 2 factor authentication.

Comment: i turned on less secure on and off 2 factor off

Comment: solved this issue! i changed email port from 578 to 587